# How to log in to Discord using token and selenium (python)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, discord, local-storage

I wrote a code in `Python` using `selenium` model to log in to discord by **token** number.

token number must be added to `localStorage`, so I ran javascript code to add the token and It's added, but when I go to Application -> localStorage -> https://discord.com I am not able to see the token key and its value. Even when I refresh the page I cannot log in, but when I added it manually I can log in when I refresh the page.

**Note:** I used this line of code to add `token` to localStorage

```py
driver.execute_script('return window.localStorage.setItem("token", "value");')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```js
function login(token) {
    setInterval(() => {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(() => {
      location.reload();
    }, 2500);
  }

login(token);
```

Inside the selenium execute_script()

Comment: Wow it really worked!
Can you explain the code?
Thank you very much

Comment: Its basically the same as yours although I am using `contentWindow.localStorage.token`

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Set the Discord token
token = 'token here'

# Configure Chrome WebDriver options
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome WebDriver in headless mode (without UI)

# Start Chrome WebDriver
webdriver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

# Open Discord login page
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")

# Inject token using JavaScript
script = f"""
    const token = "{token}";
    setInterval(() => {{
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${{token}}"`;
    }}, 50);
    setTimeout(() => {{
        location.reload();
    }}, 2500);
"""
driver.execute_script(script)

# Wait for the login process to complete
time.sleep(5)

# Verify if login was successful (you can add your own logic here)
if "discord.com/app" in driver.current_url:
    print("Login Successful")
else:
    print("Login Failed")

# Close the Chrome WebDriver
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

token = "your token"

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
driver = Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.discord.com/login")
time.sleep(3)

driver.execute_script('window.t = "' + token + '";window.localStorage = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage;window.setInterval(() => window.localStorage.token = `"${window.t}"`); window.location.reload();')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).